# Word2Vec Model Storing Model in Single Part

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

```
val model: org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Word2VecModel = new Word2Vec().setNumPartitions(20).setInputCol("value").setOutputCol("feature").fit(copus)
word2VecModel.save(s"$HDFS_URL/w2vmodel")
```

When I saves this Model then it is creating only single partition under data folder `part-r-0000-988jdu-sduj76-jh433.snappy.parquet`
with size `900 MB`

```
val model: org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Word2VecModel =Word2VecModel.load("$HDFS_URL/w2vmodel")
```

So when I Am loading this Model then I Am Getting `OutOfMemory` Exception

Is There Any way This model can be save with Multiple part of parquet or any thing else

I Am newbee so any Suggestion will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coincidentally this problem has been [recently discussed on the developers lists](http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/Why-are-ml-models-repartition-1-d-in-save-methods-td20581.html) and this discussion resulted in a JIRA ticket and pull request:

- [SPARK-19247](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19247) - *improve ml word2vec save/load*
- https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/16607

If you want a quick solution you can try to use MLlib implementation with Spark 2.0 or later ([SPARK-11994](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-11994)).